# Toggle Subdivision modifier and smooth shading with one key

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut, subdivision-surface

Is there a hotkey, script or addon to globally toggle smooth shading and subD?

When modeling with subD's I like having the shading faceted, but obviously want to see it smooth when I turn the subD modifier on. I figured out how to use the Simplify to turn subD on/off on all meshes with one button, but this doesn't change the smoothing (1st picture). So I have to go into every object, select all and adjust smooth shading whenever I want to preview my model.

Is there a way to toggle [smooth shading off/subD off] and [smooth shading on/subD on] with one hotkey? In Modo this happens when pressing Tab (2nd picture).

[image: Blender]
[image: Modo]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You can get it using Python.

I used a template "Operator Simple". And I added subsurf and smooth to an object to know the names of this functions:

[image]

Next, I replaced default main() function by this functions:

```
def main(context):
        bpy.ops.object.subdivision_set(level=2)
        bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
```

It gives subsurf and smoth, but never gets back.

To create a toggle, you need to know about programming. I writed this code:

```
def main(context):
    test=True
    for md in context.active_object.modifiers:
        if(md.type=='SUBSURF'):
            if(md.levels==2):
                test=False;
                break
    if(test):
        bpy.ops.object.subdivision_set(level=2)
        bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
    else:
        bpy.ops.object.subdivision_set(level=0)
        bpy.ops.object.shade_flat()
```

It checks for subsurf level 2, and if finds, removes Subsurf and smooth.

Finally, I can use this function by finding it in spacebar menu:
[image]

Also, you can add sourtcut:
[image]

### UPD: For making it works in Edit Mode

You noted what script doesn't work in Edit Mode. It is because shade_smooth() doesn't work in Edit Mode. So lets try to enter Object Mode, do subsurf and smooth operations and return to edit mode.

Get the current mode, and save:

```
if(context.mode!='OBJECT'):
    returnto=context.mode
```

Return to edit mode:

```
if(returnto):
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=returnto)
```

### Full code

(you can save it as .py file and install it like add-on):

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Subsmoth",
    "author": "Subsmoth",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 78, 0),
    "location": "",
    "description": "Toggle Subsurf and smooth",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "3D View",
    }
import bpy


def main(context):
    test=True
    for md in context.active_object.modifiers:
        if(md.type=='SUBSURF'):
            if(md.levels==2):
                test=False;
                break
    returnto=False        
    if(context.mode!='OBJECT'):
        returnto=context.mode
        if(returnto=='EDIT_MESH'):
            returnto='EDIT'
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    if(returnto=='EDIT' or returnto==False):    
        if(test):
            bpy.ops.object.subdivision_set(level=2)
            bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
        else:
            bpy.ops.object.subdivision_set(level=0)
            bpy.ops.object.shade_flat()
    if(returnto):
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=returnto)


class SubsmothOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.subsmooth"
    bl_label = "Subsmoth"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SubsmothOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SubsmothOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Fantastic - thanks a lot of this, it's definitely gets me 90% there. It works great in object mode, but is there also a way to make it work in edit mode? It gives me:

RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.shade_flat.poll() failed, context is incorrect

Comment: @Hybelkanin Ok, I have improved my script

Comment: It works like a charm now. I toggle the modifier about every 10 sec, so all the clicks used to be a hassle. You just ironed out a big wrinkle in my workflow - many thanks!