# How to shade smooth using BPY

Tags: python, scripting, operator

New to `bpy` and I'd like to write some code that sets the shading of an object to smooth by just clicking a button. I did some research and I have written the following lines for now:

```
import bpy

def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    row = layout.row()
    row.operator(" bpy.ops.object.shade_flat()")
    row = layout.row()
    row.operator(" mesh.object.shade_smooth()")
```

I assume that I would have to add some other lines in order to register the class and all that right? Anyway, the problem is that the code does not work. Is this the way it is supposed to work at all?

**Q:** What's the correct way to call this function when pressing a custom button?

Comment: Or row.operator("object.shade_smooth")?

Comment: @lemon object has no attribute "shade_smooth"

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167862/how-to-create-a-button-on-the-n-panel

Comment: Did you used the quotes, as I indicated above?

Comment: @lemon the problem is solved but what if i have a bunch of actions to do in a single click?

Comment: For *"a bunch of actions"* you need to understand the principles, I recommend read the post linked by batFINGER: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167862/how-to-create-a-button-on-the-n-panel

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71190/toggle-subdivision-modifier-and-smooth-shading-with-one-key